# OpenURL: opening wallet/passbook app with add a card screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to open the passbook/wallet app from my native app and navigate to add a card option in the passbook/wallet app.

What I know is shoebox:// is the URL for opening passbook/wallet app. Is there a way to open the specific screen(add a card).

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: No We can not open in this way.